# how to replace a hard coded value with a variable?

Tags: jquery

I want to replace the hard coded string "Categories" with a variable. How can I do that?
Instead of having Categories all the time, the word Categories may be replaced by the value held by a variable id, `var id`.

```
$(this).closest('ul').append('<li><input type="hidden" name="Categories.Index" value=' + newValue + ' /><input type="text" value=""  name="Categories[' + newValue + '].Name" style="width:280px"/><input type="hidden" value=""  name="Categories[' + newValue + '].ID" style="width:280px"/><input type="button"  value= "Add" /> </li>');
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. You are using variables there already - what is your question?

Comment: Why don't you just edit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437788/code-no-longer-working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var id = 'Categories';
$(this).closest('ul').append('<li><input type="hidden" name="' + id + '.Index" value=' + newValue + ' /><input type="text" value=""  name="' + id + '[' + newValue + '].Name" style="width:280px"/><input type="hidden" value=""  name="' + id + '[' + newValue + '].ID" style="width:280px"/><input type="button"  value= "Add" /> </li>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Just concat it the same way you already do with newValue:

```
name="' + id + '[' + newValue + '].ID"
```

Do the same for every occurence of Categories.